Multi-index lookup between 2 dataframes
I have 2 dataframes: one that acts as a lookup dataframe, and another that I insert values into where numerous rows match between them.
The lookup dataframe looks like this:
data1 = {
    'store': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'department': ['produce', 'produce', 'produce', 'bakery', 'meat', 'bakery'],
    'task': ['water', 'stock', 'water', 'bread', 'stock', 'doughnuts'],
    'employee': ['232', '111', '232', '121', '333', '121'],
    'step': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
    'month_year_date': ['1991-01', '1991-01', '1991-01', '1991-02', '1991-03', '1991-02'],
    'work_time': [1.2, 2.4, 1.1, 4.0, 1.5, 3.5]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)




store
department
task
employee
step
month_year_date
work_time




1
produce
water
232
A
1991-01
1.2


1
produce
stock
111
B
1991-01
2.4


1
produce
water
232
C
1991-01
1.1


1
bakery
bread
121
A
1991-02
4.0


1
meat
stock
333
C
1991-03
1.5


1
bakery
doughnuts
121
A
1991-02
3.5



and the insert dataframe looks like this:
data2 = {
    'store': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'department': ['produce', 'produce', 'produce', 'bakery', 'meat', 'bakery'],
    'task': ['water', 'stock', 'water', 'bread', 'stock', 'doughnuts'],
    'employee': ['232', '111', '232', '121', '333', '121'],
    'step': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
    'month_year_date': ['1991-01', '1991-01', '1991-02', '1991-02', '1991-03', '1991-02']}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df_2[['A', 'B', 'C']] = 0




store
department
task
employee
step
month_year_date
A
B
C




1
produce
water
232
A
1991-01
0
0
0


1
produce
stock
111
B
1991-01
0
0
0


1
produce
water
232
A
1991-02
0
0
0


1
bakery
bread
121
A
1991-02
0
0
0


1
meat
stock
333
C
1991-03
0
0
0


1
bakery
doughnuts
121
A
1991-02
0
0
0



My goal is to modify df_2 so that each each row is a unique combination of store, department, task, employee, step, and month_year_date with the values for columns A, B, C corresponding to the work_time from df_1. I'm currently using something like this:
for i in range(len(df_2)):
    indx = np.where(
        (df_2.department[i] == df_1.department)
        & (df_2.task[i] == df_1.task)
        & (df_2.employee[i] == df_1.employee)
        & (df_2.month_year_date[i] == df_1.month_year_date))
    for n in range(0, len(indx[0])):
        df_2.loc[i, df_1.step[indx[0][n]]] = df_1.loc[indx[0][n]].work_time




store
department
task
employee
step
month_year_date
A
B
C




1
produce
water
232
A
1991-01
1.2
0
1.1


1
produce
stock
111
B
1991-01
0
2.4
0


1
produce
water
232
A
1991-02
0
0
0


1
bakery
bread
121
A
1991-02
4.0
0
0


1
meat
stock
333
C
1991-03
0
0
1.5


1
bakery
doughnuts
121
A
1991-02
3.5
0
0



which yields what I'm looking for, but it takes a significant amount of time given larger dataframes (2+ million rows).
Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this task? I know that nested for loops create exponential time complexities, and would love to speed this step up!

df_1.department[i] == df_1.department - Is that correct? Comparing with the other ones, it looks like it should be df_2.department[i] == df_1.department, but I've never seen this usage of np.where() before so I'm not sure what that step is doing. BTW the docs say to prefer np.nonzero() instead of np.where() for that.

Is it possible you could reduce the number of key columns for the sake of example? I think 2 would be fine instead of 6. For reference see How to make good reproducible pandas examples

I'm trying to understand the underlying task here, and one thing's bugging me: if the columns A, B, C correspond to the step, then why is step still a column in the resulting df_2? My guess is you actually want to pivot but don't realize it.

Is this what you're looking for? How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?

@wjandrea thanks for your comments and helpful edits. You are correct, pivot is exactly what I was looking for.

This is a straight-forward pivot from what you describe.
df_2 = df_1.pivot_table(
    index=['store', 'department', 'task', 'employee', 'month_year_date'],
    columns='step', values='work_time', fill_value=0, aggfunc=numpy.sum
).reset_index()

